# Lof Slider - pause on hover

Tags: jquery, hover, slider, mouseover

I am using jQuery Lof Slider Version: 3.0.2. There are no option like:

```
PauseOnHover: true
```

How can I do this directly in the plugin code?

[Plugin Code](http://jsfiddle.net/nRBPq/)

[Live Example](http://ingozoell.de/lof/)

Thanks
Ogni

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this slider works as I can only see the plugin JavaScript and not a working example. But this should be fairly easy to implement yourself.

You could add a simple `hover()` handler to the slideshow to call the `stop()` function and quickly looking through I think the animation start function is called `fxStart()`. This is just an idea but see below for something similar to what might work.

```
$('#SlideshowArea').hover(
   function(){
      $('#slideshow').stop();
   },
   function(){
      $('#slideshow').fxStart();
   }
);
```

Comment: Hi vletech, thank you for your answer. I added a [live example:](http://ingozoell.de/lof)